# Can we set a UIViewControllers view as a section Headerview in a UITableViewController?

Tags: uitableview, sectionheader

Can we set a UIViewControllers view as a section Headerview in a UITableViewController.

Like,

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
CellHeader *cellHeader  = [[CellHeader alloc] initWithNibName:@"CellHeader" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
return cellHeader.view;
}
```

Comment: Yes you can set any `UIView` to section Headerview.

Comment: But When I use this i Got a crash ending at the point select$DARWIN_EXTSN. Will this headerview created each time when the cell is reloaded.